# Proof of $\mathbf{x}^{T}A\mathbf{x}=0\Rightarrow A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

As far as I know, for any $A$:
$$\mathbf{x}^{T}A\mathbf{y}=0;\forall\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in R^n\Rightarrow A=0$$

Does it mean that
$$\mathbf{x}^{T}A\mathbf{x}=0;\forall\mathbf{x}\in R^n\Rightarrow A=0$$

The condition of the first claim $\forall\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in R^n$ implies that we could take $y=x$, and, therefore the second claim should hold. Correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: Choosing two entities freely is a greater degree of freedom than being able to choose only one. Consider $$A = \begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: And to add to Daniel's comment, with $\mathbf{x} = \pmatrix{ 1 \\ 0 }$, his matrix gives $\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. I see the contradiction to my claim, but I still don't understand what's wrong with reasoning?

Comment: There is however a case where it is true that $x^TAx=0$ for all $x$ implies $A=0$: If we can write $A$ as $B^TB$ for some $B$. (For example, a real, symmetric matrix $A$ has this form iff it has nonnegative eigenvalues.)

Comment: @fuglede: The point of Daniel's comment is that $x^{T} A x=0$ for *any* vector $x$, not just $\pmatrix{ 1 \\ 0 }$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your conclusion is false. The problem with your reasoning is that the first claim reads (in plain English):

> If, for all $x$ and $y$, $x^TAy=0$, then $A=0$.

When you set $y=x$ then you are no longer considering all $x$ and $y$, only the pairs $x,y$ such that $y=x$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Now, it looks so obvious. Thank you, Alex)

Comment: We should note, however, that if $x^T A x = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then we may conclude that $A=0$.

Comment: @nullUser No. Consider Daniel Fischer's example. If $x=\binom{a}{b}$ then we have $x^TAx=(a\;b)\binom{-b}{a}=a(-b)+ba=0$ for all $a,b$ in any field.

Comment: @AlexBecker Apologies, I meant if $x^* A x = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then we may conclude that $A=0$. I forgot that the inner product involved complex conjugation.

Comment: In general, if $X$ is an inner-product space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $A \in \mathcal{L}(X,X)$ is such that $(Ax,x)=0$ for all $x \in X$, then $A=0$.

Comment: @nullUser Ah yes that makes sense. Since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, if $A\ne 0$ then it has a nonzero eigenvalue, say with eigenvector $x$, so $(Ax,x)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^T A x = 0 \; \forall x => (x, Ax) = 0 \; \forall x$, hence $A$ can be an orthogonal matrix. This is what A in the @Daniel Fisher's counterexample is.

Comment: A *particular* orthogonal matrix, for example a rotation of $\pi/2$ in the plane that transforms every vector in one orthogonal to it.